# How do I know whether to return the left pointer or right pointer in a binary search problem?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I was solving LeetCode problem [875. Koko Eating Bananas](https://leetcode.com/problems/koko-eating-bananas/):

> Koko loves to eat bananas. There are `n` piles of bananas, the `i`<sup>th</sup> pile has `piles[i]` bananas. The guards have gone and will come back in `h` hours.
>
> Koko can decide her bananas-per-hour eating speed of `k`. Each hour, she chooses some pile of bananas and eats `k` bananas from that pile. If the pile has less than `k` bananas, she eats all of them instead and will not eat any more bananas during this hour.
>
> Koko likes to eat slowly but still wants to finish eating all the bananas before the guards return.
>
> Return *the minimum integer* `k` *such that she can eat all the bananas within* `h` *hours*.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - **Input:** `piles = [3,6,7,11], h = 8`
> - **Output:** `4`

This is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def minEatingSpeed(self, piles: List[int], h: int) -> int:
        lp=1
        rp=max(piles)
        while lp<=rp:
            speed=(lp+rp)//2
            hours=0
            for pile in piles:
                hours+=ceil(pile/speed)
            if hours>h:
                lp=speed+1
            else:
                rp=speed-1
        return lp
```

### Problem

When I returned the right pointer here, it failed the test cases. But, when I used the left pointer it passed.

### Question

Is there a general approach to know whether to return the left pointer or right pointer to a binary search problem?

I just did trial and error here.  I want to know why this is, not just for this problem, but in general binary search problems.

Comment: The problem is that `//2` rounds down. So `rp=speed-1` can double-decrement `rp`. For example, if `lp=4` and `rp=5`, then `speed` is 4, and `rp=speed-1` sets `rp` to 3. That's clearly not a correct answer since by the definition of `lp`, when `lp` is 4, the correct answer must not be less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

As your `while` condition has `lp<=rp`, then by consequence the code *after* that loop will have a different value for `lp` and `rp`.

When the `if` condition within the `while` loop is true, we know for sure that `speed` is no longer a candidate solution, so it is correct to exclude it with `lp=speed+1`. However, when the `if` condition is not true, we don't know whether `speed` can be excluded. Yet your `else` block excludes it with `rp=speed-1`. This means that `rp` is unreliable: it can be one unit off and surely *will* be one unit off when the loop exits: this explains why your code fails when you return `rp`.

Taking a step back, there are two issues with this binary search implementation:

- `rp=speed-1` should be `rp=speed` because `speed` is still a potential solution and should not be excluded from the `lp-rp` window.
- `while lp<=rp` should be `while lp<rp` because both `lp` and `rp` are supposed to be potential solutions; if they are equal, there is only one solution left and no further iteration should be necessary. With the first change above, this change is required, as otherwise an infinite loop will occur.

With these changes, it doesn't matter anymore whether you return `lp` or `rp`, as they are guaranteed to be equal after the loop has ended.

Not the issue, but instead of `ceil(pile/speed)`, avoid conversion to floating point  and do `(pile + speed - 1) // speed`